# How to make dialog box in ASP.Net using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying make a dialog box using model. But I am not getting an output. Here is my code

**Header Files**

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="js/Report-Filter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ReportTotalSalesPivot.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/Accordian-Hide-Show.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/Accordian-Hide-Show.js"></script>

    <link href="css/ReportTotalSalesPivot-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

**Inside Body**

```
<input id="btnSave opener" class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="SAVE" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Some txt goes here</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wrapper').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Basic Dialog'
    });
    $('#opener').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please don't suggest this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cWG2w/). From here only i got the code. I think the problem with arranging links in head tag.

I got error message. I think that error is not related to this model.

**Error msg**

> jquery-3.1.1.js:6170           GET http://localhost:55047/css/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: why negative marks? Is that anything wrong?

Comment: try to see if you are getting any error in the browser console. ( PS: i am not the one who downvoted)

Comment: @it'satrap That error msg I already added. please check

Comment: This is an incorrect way to define an id to an element `id="btnSave opener"`. Either change it to `id="btnSave"` (Recommended) or `id="opener"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button `id` to one without spaces. You cannot use a space inside an id. It looks like you are using it in the same way as `class`, where you can add multiple values.

```
<input id="btnSave" class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="SAVE" />
```

Then the modal will open if you modify the jQuery listener.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
});
```

And those images you are missing can be [downloaded here](http://jqueryui.com/download/). They are included in the UI download.

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange the Header Tag like below. Below are working code. Header file sequence is important.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Modal PopUp</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#showmodal").click(function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="showmodal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    This is the test modal pop-up.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```